# How to prevent Jackson from (de)serializing certain properties?

Tags: java, json, jackson, kotlin

For any Kotlin class, one method is generated for every public property in the format `componentX()`, so this class:

```
public data class Dog(public var name: String, public var age: Double)
```

Is equivalent to something like this in Java:

```
public class Dog {
    private String name;
    private double age;

    public Dog(@NotNull String name, @NotNull double age) {
        // assign values
    }

    // Getters and setters for name and age
    // toString(), equals(), and hashCode()

    public String component1() { return name; }
    public double component2() { return age;  }
}
```

This messes with Jackson, as it views it as each `componentX()` method *and* each `getXxx()` method as a (de)serialization target.

The way I have been getting around this up until now is by creating all of my models in Java instead, which is not preferred.

In short, how can I configure the ObjectMapper so that it ignores `componentX()` methods?

Comment: I have never seen this behaviour in Jackson with Kotlin, with or without the [Jackson Module for Kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin).  There must be some other cause.  Your accepted answer is not correct either for solving this case.  Please review the other answer and if you still have the problem, show your code that setups the `ObjectMapper` and calls `writeValue` or whatever method you use.  Are you using really old Jackson before 2.5.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** *the details of @JsonFilter described in the accepted answer are not needed*

Nothing beyond default behavior of Jackson is needed.  Using current and recent Jackson versions there is no such behaviour such as described.  Sometimes Google shows an old version that is packaged as `org.codehaus.*` instead of `com.fasterxml.*`

In Jackson, if the property does not look like a JavaBean property, it would not be deserialized.  And `componentX` do not look like JavaBean properties.

Here is a test case that proves using both raw Jackson and also it combined with the [Jackson Module for Kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) both work as expected, and neither has this issue.

```
class StackOverflowTest {
    public data class Dog(public var name: String, public var age: Double)

    @Test public fun testSimpleDeser() {
        val dogObj = Dog("Avi", 1.5)
        val expectedJson = """{"name":"Avi","age":1.5}"""

        assertEquals(expectedJson, ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dogObj))
        assertEquals(expectedJson, jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dogObj))
    }
}
```

I ran the test with Jackson `2.6.4` but I am sure that none of `2.5.x`, `2.6.x`, or `2.7.x` have this issue since those have all been used with Kotlin for a long time now.

Answer (score 1):

Besides a custom serializer/deserializer take a look at @JsonFilter.  It can be applied using a mixin and you can use custom logic such as filtering out all properties that start with componentX if you want.

Here is the documentation which explains how you can create a custom filter:
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter  It's pretty straightforward to do.

There may be a better way but this should work.

Edit:  Also look at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews.  This is more of a static way of defining properties that can be ignored so I don't think this would work for you and filters are probably better.

Comment: This is not needed @thatJavaNerd, with any recent Jackson I have never seen this behavior.  See the other answer and associated unit test.